# Guardar arrays de arrays laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

Tengo un formulario el cual filtra registros por semana y necesito guardarlos en mi bd, si mando solo un input si guardar el problema es que nose como guardar mas de un input
esta es mi funcion

```
public function store(Request $request) {
       $moneda = $request->input('moneda');
       $familia = $request->input('familia');
       foreach($moneda as $p){
           ventas3::insert(['moneda'=>$p]);
       }
       foreach($familia as $u){
           ventas3::insert(['familia'=>$u]);
       }
   }
```

Solamente me guarda lo que esta en moneda pero no lo que esta en familia,
Esta mi vista

```
  <tbody>
                                @foreach ($ventas1 as $ventas)
                                <tr>
                                   <td> {{$ventas->FECHA}}
                                        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" value="{{$ventas->FECHA}}" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha[]"
                                                style="width:120px;height:40px" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" value="{{$ventas->MONEDA}}" class="form-control" id="moneda" style="width:60px;height:40px" name="moneda[]" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" value="{{$ventas->FAMILIA}}" class="form-control" id="familia" style="width:120px;height:40px" name="familia[]" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
```

El error que me genera es el siguiente
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'moneda' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ventas` (`familia`) values (EQUIPO ELECTRICO))

Answer (score 0):

En realidad los formularios están limitados para lo que deseas hacer. Lamentablemente los arreglos de inputs (`fecha[]`) sirven para enviar multiples valores bajo la misma llave, pero no son asociativos a un objeto.

**Ejemplo**

1.- tienes campos A B C

2.- Agregas inputs para agregar los datos A B C

3.- Agregas inputs para agregar los datos A B C

4.- Agregas inputs para agregar los datos A C

Cuando recibas los respectivos inputs recibirás `A A A | B B | C C C` pero no tendrás la más minima idea de cual es el objeto que le falta una `B` (La posición de los datos no es determinante).

La mejor forma de trabajar datos de este tipo es construyendo tus objetos en javascript para luego enviarlos como parte del cuerpo de una petición ajax al backend.

Si no sabes por donde partir, puedes leer la [guia de desarrollo de developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) para conocer ajax y por tu cuenta puedes leer más sobre peticiones HTTP para entender la diferencia entre los encabezados, el cuerpo de la petición y los parametros de formulario.

volviendo a laravel, luego obtienes el cuerpo de la petición desde el request (y lo decodificas para que sea un objeto manipulable):

`json_decode($request->getContent(), true);`

Si quieres aplicar validaciones sobre el request, una vez decodificada la petición puedes usar `Validator::make(TU_OBJETO_DECODIFICADO, TUS_REGLAS);`